# Remove button text using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Hello I am using a slider that generates a button and gives it some text. I am wondering if there is some way to remove this text using jQuery. I am not able to edit the html because it is being generated by the slider.

Here is my HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="slick-next">Next</button>
```

As you can see it is giving the button a text of "Next" I would like to completely remove it so it looks like:

```
<button type="button" class="slick-next"></button>
```

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: `$(".slick-next").text("");`

Comment: thanks andrew, that worked perfectly. could you post it as an answer so I can give you some reputation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Andrew commented, using jQuery you can replate existing text with empty text:

```
$(".slick-next").text("");
//or
$(".slick-next").html("");
```

Also using Vanilla Javascript, you can achieve the same effect:

```
document.querySelector('.slick-next').innerHTML = "";
//or
document.querySelector('.slick-next').innerText = "";
```

The last solution is the best at my opinion, because you completely get rid of unnecessary text node inside the element:

```
// vanilla js
var element = document.querySelector('.slick-next');
element.removeChild(element.childNodes[0]);

// jQuery version
$(".slick-next").empty();
```